# How to find differences between a file and a history of a corresponding file in a git repository?

Tags: git, git-diff

I have a local file and a corresponding file in a git repository. They aren't in sync so I want to find differences between them but only if a particular line of that file has never existed in the history of the corresponding file in the git repository. For example:

```
# a.txt (the local file)
foo
bar <- this line has never existed in the corresponding repo
baz <- this line existed but was intentionally removed in the past
```

```
# b.txt (the corresponding file in the git)
foo
```

Then the only difference between files `a.txt` and `b.txt` should be `bar` because `baz` doesn't exist now but it existed in the past.

I'm looking for an answer how it can be achieved in the simplest way.

Comment: Search in web for Diff and Merge Tool. There many of them